# Confusion about countable topological basis for the real line

Tags: general-topology

My topology textbook states that a countable basis for the real line can be formed by the open intervals $(a, b)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$. But I'm confused about how this can be a complete basis without including irrational numbers. For instance, the interval $(0, \sqrt{2})$ is open, so it should be possible to express it as a union of the basis sets, but I don't see how this can be done if the basis sets all have rational endpoints.

Comment: How many rational numbers are there between $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(0, \sqrt{2}) = \bigcup_{0 < r < \sqrt{2}, r \in \mathbb{Q}}{(0, r)}.$$
In general you can approximate any real from the left or right with rationals arbitrarily closely, allowing you to express any open interval as a countable union of open intervals with rational endpoints (and hence any open set can be written as a countable union of open intervals with rational endpoints).

More concretely (and with a bit more efficiency than the above union), using the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ as a method for approximating $\sqrt{2}$ aribtrarily closely from the left:
$$(0, \sqrt{2}) = (0, 1) \cup (0, 1.4) \cup (0, 1.41) \cup (0, 1.414) \cup (0, 1.4142) \cup \cdots$$